# Python give number of args to an imported function

Tags: python, function, arguments

I'm trying to give an argument to an imported function.
I have `base.py`:

```
import sc1 #import sc1.py
from threading import Thread

Thread(target=sc1.main,args="John").start()
```

And a function in `sc1.py`:

```
def main(name):
    print "Hello ",name
```

Say

> TypeError: main() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)

If I give just one `args="J"` then it works fine,
does anyone have any idea what I can do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to pass a tuple of args:

```
Thread(target=sc1.main,args=("John",)).start()
```

In your case, since `str` are iterable, the `Thread` is trying to unpack `"J" "o", "h", "n"` as the arguments rather than passing the entire thing as an atomic unit.

Answer (score 2):

Call the `Thread` as:

```
Thread(target=sc1.main,args=["John"]).start()
```

**Explaination:**

It is throwing error in your case because `args` is expected to be of `list` or `tuple` type. And when your are passing `"John"`, it is getting passed as `["J", "o", "h", "n"]` i.e. array of `chars`